# combine multidimensional array to one array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array on my project and I want to merge them as 1 dimensional array

```
"results": [
        {
            "code": "jne",
            "name": "Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)",
            "costs": [
                {
                    "service": "OKE",
                    "description": "Ongkos Kirim Ekonomis",
                    "cost": [
                        {
                            "value": 50000,
                            "etd": "4-5 HARI",
                            "note": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "service": "REG",
                    "description": "Layanan Reguler",
                    "cost": [
                        {
                            "value": 55000,
                            "etd": "2-3 HARI",
                            "note": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "service": "YES",
                    "description": "Yakin Esok Sampai",
                    "cost": [
                        {
                            "value": 145000,
                            "etd": "1-1 HARI",
                            "note": ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want it to look like following if you make a table of this results:

[image]

Anyone can help me with my problem?

Comment: You should include what you have tried so far or if you haven't tried anything at all then try it as best as you can then come back here if you're stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [Demo](https://eval.in/908198)

Here is code snippet

```
<?php


$json_string = <<<EOF
{

"results": [
        {
            "code": "jne",
            "name": "Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)",
            "costs": [
                {
                    "service": "OKE",
                    "description": "Ongkos Kirim Ekonomis",
                    "cost": [
                        {
                            "value": 50000,
                            "etd": "4-5 HARI",
                            "note": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "service": "REG",
                    "description": "Layanan Reguler",
                    "cost": [
                        {
                            "value": 55000,
                            "etd": "2-3 HARI",
                            "note": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "service": "YES",
                    "description": "Yakin Esok Sampai",
                    "cost": [
                        {
                            "value": 145000,
                            "etd": "1-1 HARI",
                            "note": ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
EOF;


// json string to php array
$array = json_decode($json_string, true);

// output array
$output = array();

// loop through array
foreach($array['results'] as $item)
{
   $main_fields = array( 'code' => $item['code'], 'name' => $item['name'] );
   foreach($item['costs'] as $sub ){
          $t = $sub['cost'][0];
              unset($sub['cost']);
              $tmp = array_merge($main_fields, $sub, $t);
              $output[] = $tmp;  
   } 

}

// print contents
print_r($output);


// to get html table 
// iterate array $output or else inside above loop you can do it

echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr>\n<th>".implode("</th>\n<th>", array_keys($output[0]))."</th>\n</tr>\n";
foreach($output as $row){
   echo "<tr>\n<td>".implode("</td>\n<td>", $row)."</td>\n</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>"

?>
```

Would Produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => jne
            [name] => Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)
            [service] => OKE
            [description] => Ongkos Kirim Ekonomis
            [value] => 50000
            [etd] => 4-5 HARI
            [note] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => jne
            [name] => Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)
            [service] => REG
            [description] => Layanan Reguler
            [value] => 55000
            [etd] => 2-3 HARI
            [note] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => jne
            [name] => Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)
            [service] => YES
            [description] => Yakin Esok Sampai
            [value] => 145000
            [etd] => 1-1 HARI
            [note] => 
        )

)
<table>
<tr>
<th>code</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>service</th>
<th>description</th>
<th>value</th>
<th>etd</th>
<th>note</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>jne</td>
<td>Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)</td>
<td>OKE</td>
<td>Ongkos Kirim Ekonomis</td>
<td>50000</td>
<td>4-5 HARI</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>jne</td>
<td>Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)</td>
<td>REG</td>
<td>Layanan Reguler</td>
<td>55000</td>
<td>2-3 HARI</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>jne</td>
<td>Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)</td>
<td>YES</td>
<td>Yakin Esok Sampai</td>
<td>145000</td>
<td>1-1 HARI</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code I can make it become one dimensional array
Your code is so usefull
Thank you verymuch

Comment: Ok, actually this is my first time asking in stack overflow

Comment: Just to mention this is still considered multidimensional array and not single dimensional. In order to access it's values you will need to loop around it. Other than that it's the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but looking in your array this is not possible. `Array-keys` can only be unique and in your case you ***need*** to have multidimensional array. Check the nested array `costs`. You will see that each array position has the same key names. So it's not possible to make this array into 1 dimension.

I suggest this [source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to help you understand arrays better.

Comment: Thanks for your sugestion I will read again so I can became a great developer like you guys
Thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a cycle:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($myArray["results"] as $item) {
    $name = $item["name"];
    $code = str_replace(")", "", str_replace("(", "", substr($name, strpos($name, "("))));
    $name = trim(substr($name, 0, strpos($name, "(") - 1));
    foreach ($item["costs"] as $cost) {
        $service = $cost["service"];
        $description = $cost["description"];
        foreach ($cost["cost"] as $costItem) {
            $result[]= array(
                "code" => $code,
                "name" => $name,
                "service" => $service,
                "description" => $description,
                "value" => $costItem["value"],
                "edt" => $costItem["etd"],
                "note" => $costItem["note"]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your usefull code
Now I can get my work done 
You guys are the best

Comment: @Euclides you are welcome! You might consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem.